# preg_grep to check only 3 specific letters exist

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to use preg_grep to return an array of only keys matched with the existence of 3 specific letters i.e.

array as follows:

```
$testArray = array(
'XXL' => array(),
'XL' => array(),
'L' => array(),
'M' => array(),
'S' => array(),
'XS' => array()
);
```

I want to run something like (if I can get it to work :) )

```
$res = preg_grep('[^XLS]', $testArray);
```

and get a returned array without the 'M' key i.e.

```
$res = array(
'XXL' => array(),
'XL' => array(),
'L' => array(),
'S' => array(),
'XS' => array()
);
```

I've tried multiple regex's but I get either all the keys or none, can anyone help please??

Many thanks,
Kieron

Comment: ref: [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-grep.php): `Return array entries that match the pattern`. Also, the first comment on the manual page includes a usable function for your problem.

Comment: Indeed and unfortunately I tried that without using array_keys which was the problem pointed out by Amal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep) will not work with multi-dimensional arrays. You'll have to fetch the keys separately using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) and apply `preg_grep()` on that. Now use [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) in conjunction with [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) to create the result array:

```
$keys = preg_grep('/[XLS]/', array_keys($testArray));
$result = array_intersect_key($testArray, array_flip($keys));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [XXL] => Array
        (
        )

    [XL] => Array
        (
        )

    [L] => Array
        (
        )

    [S] => Array
        (
        )

    [XS] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/134489)

Comment: except this regex will only validate one letter keys containing either X, L or S

Comment: @Sebastien: If you read the documentation for `preg_grep()`, you will be able to see that: "*array consisting of the elements of the input array that match the given pattern.*". Which is exactly what the character class does (and what the OP was originally trying to do in his question).

Comment: @Amal Murali my bad just realise you didn't put any regex delimiters inside your expression... god I feel stupid...(^$)

Comment: @Sebastien: I didn't put any delimiters *inside* the expression, but I've got one (`/`) wrapping the expression. In case you got confused reading the question: `[XLS]` was meant as a character class, not `[` followed by `X`, `L`, `S`, followed by `]`. :)